# Manipulating javascript array of objects to obtain a new set of array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array of objects

```
const unitsAndRates = [
  {
    propertyUnitType: "store",
    propertyUnitRate: "20000",
    numberOfUnit: 4
  },
  {
    propertyUnitType: "duplex",
    propertyUnitRate: "20000",
    numberOfUnit: 3
  }
];
```

and I need something like this generated array from the one above.

```
const generated = [
  {
    propertyUnitType: "store1",
    propertyUnitRate: "20000"
  },
  {
    propertyUnitType: "store2",
    propertyUnitRate: "20000"
  },
  {
    propertyUnitType: "store3",
    propertyUnitRate: "20000"
  },
  {
    propertyUnitType: "store4",
    propertyUnitRate: "20000"
  },
  {
    propertyUnitType: "duplex1",
    propertyUnitRate: "20000"
  },
  {
    propertyUnitType: "duplex2",
    propertyUnitRate: "20000"
  },
  {
    propertyUnitType: "duplex3",
    propertyUnitRate: "20000"
  }
];
```

How can I generate the output above considering the `numberOfUnit`?

Comment: What are the rules for the duplication and what did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using `Array.prototype.flatMap`.

```js
const unitsAndRates = [
  {
    propertyUnitType: "store",
    propertyUnitRate: "20000",
    numberOfUnit: 4
  },
  {
    propertyUnitType: "duplex",
    propertyUnitRate: "20000",
    numberOfUnit: 3
  }
];

const result = unitsAndRates.flatMap((item) => [...Array(item.numberOfUnit).keys()].map((index) => ({
  propertyUnitType: item.propertyUnitType + (index + 1),
  propertyUnitRate: item.propertyUnitRate
})));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unitsAndRates.map(item => ({
  propertyUnitType: item.propertyUnitType,
  propertyUnitRate: item.propertyUnitRate
}))
```

or

```
unitsAndRates.map({propertyUnitType, propertyUnitRate} => ({propertyUnitType, propertyUnitRate }))
```

And if you need to filter by **numberOfUnit** filed try:

```
const filteredUnits = unitsAndRates.filter(item => item.numberOfUnit === "2000")
```

and then you can do mapping

```
filteredUnits.map({propertyUnitType, propertyUnitRate} => ({propertyUnitType, propertyUnitRate }))
```